# Error When Databinding to Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, datasource

I am having trouble getting my datasource linked to my repeater through this code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //HiddenField used as a placholder
    HiddenField username = list.FindControl("username") as HiddenField;
    //list is a DataList containing all of the user names
    list.DataSource = Membership.GetAllUsers();
    list.DataBind();
    //Creates a string for each user name that is bound to the datalist
    String user = username.Value;
    //profilelist is a repeater containing all of the profile information
    //Gets the profile of every member that is bound to the DataList
    //Repeater is used to display tables of profile information for every user on
    // the site in a single webform
    profilelist.DataSource = Profile.GetProfile(user);
    profilelist.DataBind();

}
```

I am getting the error message

```
An invalid data source is being used for profilelist. A valid data source must implement either IListSource or IEnumerable.
```

Comment: what does Profile.GetProfile(user) return?

Comment: first, what is your question. second, why are you using a repeater to display the profile information?

Comment: @Etch- It is a built in method from role and membership management that gets all of the profile information of a specific user

Comment: @peroija- I need to know how to get the Profile.GetProfile(user) data bound to the profilelist Repeater. I am using a Repeater because I need the freedom it provides in regards to HTML and also I am using this UserControl to display a table containing basic information of every user from the site.

Comment: Repeaters are used for lists of objects. GetProfile returns a single instance: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.profile.profilemigrateeventargs.anonymousid.aspx

Comment: is there a built in view for the profiles in your database? you can always use that as your datasource for your profile list, or make your own view with info you need from the profiles

Comment: .aspx pages can also contain plain ol' HTML. If you want access to them in the code-behind, add `runat="server"` to the opening tag.

Comment: @TiesonT.- I understand that repeaters contain lists of objects, since I am getting a profile for evey user of my site in list form a Repeater is what I need in this application. I have set "FullMember1" as the value to save query time until I get the functionality working.

Comment: @peroija- The built in view is contained in the Profile class. It is a built in class provided by C# for the specific purpose of managing users and their profiles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to post this up but for anyone that needs to do something similar here is the code behind that works

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<MembershipUserCollection> usernamelist = new List<MembershipUserCollection>();
    usernamelist.Add(Membership.GetAllUsers());
    List<ProfileCommon> myProfileList = new List<ProfileCommon>();
        foreach (MembershipUser user in usernamelist[0])
        {
            string username = user.ToString();
            myProfileList.Add(Profile.GetProfile(username));
            Label emailLabel = profilelist.FindControl("EmailLabel") as Label;
        }
}
```

At the moment this is displaying about 15 user names and providing an ability to link to each of theses users respective profiles.

Answer (score 2):

Well the reason why it will not work is because `Profile.GetProfile` returns `ProfileCommon`.  As the error states the type you set `profilelist.Datasource` equal to, must be `IListSource` or `IEnumerable`.

I would suggest not using a repeater since you don't have actual repeating data to display.

**EDIT**

I think this is what you want to do.

```
        IEnumerable<ProfileCommon> myProfileList = new IEnumerable<ProfileCommon>();

        foreach(var user in userlist)
        {
             myProfileList.Add(Profile.GetProfile(user));
        }

        profilelist.datasource = myProfileList;
```

Comment: Any insight on how to store the information coming out of Profile.GetProfile into an IListSource or IEnumberable. The repeater is necessary because GetProfile is being called for every user of the site and all of their information is being displayed on the same page.

Comment: To turn any one item into an `IEnumerable` object: `public IEnumerable<YourType> GetEnumerable(YourType x) { yield return x; }` But you should look at the design of your application, instead of using this.

Answer (score 1):

Your going about this wrong.  As Etch said, a repeater is for *lists* of things.  GetProfile doesn't return a list.

You're better off just putting your controls in a panel and assigning them in the "list" controls ondatabinding event.

In other words, you don't need a repeater here.

Comment: If I do not use the repeater then how can I get my list of GetProfile returns to display on the page?